# After capturing image my entire fragment got recreated and in fragment lof of data

Tags: android, camera, fragment, onsaveinstancestate

In Particular device(Samsung SMT515) while capturing image App got crashed , Previously i was using normal data.getExtra("data) for fetching image but now i am using FileProvider. but still is recreating fragment and lot of data is in fragment how to save all in onSaveInstanceStae, even I am saving imageUri to onSaveInsatanceState like this:

```
      @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (custImgUri != null) {
        outState.putParcelable("custImgFileUri", custImgUri);
    }
    if (kycImgUri != null) {
        outState.putParcelable("kycFileUri", kycImgUri);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("custImgFileUri")) {
            custImgUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("custImgFileUri");
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("kycFileUri")) {
            kycImgUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("kycFileUri");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should override `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` .

Comment: doing same,  but after recreating all data come null, how to prevent them

Comment: Try with `outState.putString("custImgFileUri", custImgUri.toString());`